# Store kit module error in titanium

Tags: iphone, objective-c, module, in-app-purchase, titanium

Hi I am using store kit module in titanium.The code is working fine until i add the line of purchasing the product
My code is as follows

```
  var Storekit = require('ti.storekit'); 
Storekit.requestProducts([ 'com.example.qld.inapp' ], function (evt) {
if (!evt.success) {
    alert('ERROR: We were not able to get the product!');
}
else if (evt.invalid) {
    alert('ERROR: We requested an invalid product!');
}
else {
    alert(evt.products[0]);
   Storekit.purchase(evt);
}
});
```

and when i add the purchase line it gives the following error

```
[ERROR] Exception in event callback: {
line = 14;
message = "*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]";
sourceId = 173081376;
sourceURL = "file://localhost/Users/aadilf/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/C7C55347-5965-4C58-9624-8A41837459D4/QLD%20Best%20Bets.app/home.js";
  }
```

as i have not done objective c before i am unable to resolve this error

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying the object you want to purchase. You're purchasing the event itself (which contains a status, and zero, one, or multiple products).

```
Storekit.purchase(evt.products[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have done the same said by you but it still giving me error do you think there could be other problem

Comment: Two things: 1) your example code is wrong, which is misleading. 2) No products are being returned. As the error says, 1 is outside the bounds of 0..0. You're not getting back a valid product.